# Callback Event after successful login msal-react

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, msal-react

I'm using <MsalAuthenticationTemplate interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect}> to redirect the user to the login page. How can I perform a function after successful login? Is there a callback event I can hook in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few events available.

| Event Type | Description | Interaction Type | Payload | Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `LOGIN_START` | LoginPopup or loginRedirect is called | `Popup` or `Redirect` | [PopupRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#popuprequest) or [RedirectRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#redirectrequest) |  |
| `LOGIN_SUCCESS` | Successfully logged in | `Popup` or `Redirect` | [AuthenticationResult](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_common.html#authenticationresult) |  |
| `LOGIN_FAILURE` | Error when logging in | `Popup` or `Redirect` |  | [AuthError](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_common.autherror.html) or Error |
| `ACQUIRE_TOKEN_START` | AcquireTokenPopup or acquireTokenRedirect or acquireTokenSilent is called | `Popup` or `Redirect` or `Silent` | [PopupRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#popuprequest) or [RedirectRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#redirectrequest) or [SilentRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#silentrequest) |  |
| `ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS` | Successfully acquired token from cache or network | `Popup` or `Redirect` or `Silent` | [AuthenticationResult](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_common.html#authenticationresult) |  |
| `ACQUIRE_TOKEN_FAILURE` | Error when acquiring token | `Popup` or `Redirect` or `Silent` |  | [AuthError](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_common.autherror.html) or Error |
| `ACQUIRE_TOKEN_NETWORK_START` | Starting acquiring token from network | `Silent` |  |  |
| `SSO_SILENT_START` | SsoSilent API called | `Silent` | [SsoSilentRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#ssosilentrequest) |  |
| `SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS` | SsoSilent succeeded | `Silent` | [AuthenticationResult](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_common.html#authenticationresult) |  |
| `SSO_SILENT_FAILURE` | SsoSilent failed | `Silent` |  | [AuthError](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_common.autherror.html) or Error |
| `HANDLE_REDIRECT_START` | HandleRedirectPromise called | `Redirect` |  |  |
| `HANDLE_REDIRECT_END` | HandleRedirectPromise finished | `Redirect` |  |  |
| `LOGOUT_START` | Logout called | `Redirect` or `Popup` | [EndSessionRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#endsessionrequest) or [EndSessionPopupRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#endsessionpopuprequest) |  |
| `LOGOUT_END` | Logout finished | `Redirect` or `Popup` |  |  |
| `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` | Logout success | `Redirect` or `Popup` | [EndSessionRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#endsessionrequest) or [EndSessionPopupRequest](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#endsessionpopuprequest) |  |
| `LOGOUT_FAILURE` | Logout failed | `Redirect` or `Popup` |  | [AuthError](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_common.autherror.html) or Error |

Source: [MSAL Browser documentation - Events](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/events.md)

Looks like you're looking for the LOGIN_SUCCESS event.